Interpreting an algorithm as an integral
$\text{Consider the following algorithm:}$
s = 0
x = -1000
while x < 1000
    y = -1000
    while y < 1000
        if (x * x) + (y * y) < 1000000
            s = s + (x * x)
        y = y + 1
    x = x + 1
output s

Which of the following is closest to the output of this program?
$\text{(A) }10^6\\
\text{(B) }10^9\\
\text{(C) }10^{12}\\
\text{(D) }10^{15}\\
\text{(E) }10^{18}$

I did it in a tedious way, a way that does not involve any integration.
I got the same provided answers, which is $\text{(C) }10^{12}$

At the ANSWERS section, a hint is given, it says: "interpret the algorithm as an integral".

When I saw that hint, I could not understand how is the problem related to integration. As I see both $x$ and $y$, I guessed it should be a double integral. That is
$$\int_{-1000}^{1000}\int_{-1000}^{1000}(x^2+y^2)~\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y$$
which evaluates to $\frac{8}{3}\times 10^{12}$
Hence $\text{(C)}$ is correct.

So should it be really a double integral as I guessed?
If yes, did I set the right limits of the integrals? Or by chance I got right (with wrong settings)?
Honestly, I need more explanation on how can we convert that algorithm into an integral.
Note: No calculator is allowed.

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

My interpretation is that we are summing over the integers $x,y \in [-1000,999]$ the function $f(x,y) = x^2$, but only for those $x,y$ such that $x^2+y^2 < 1000^2$, i.e. within the circle of radius $1000$.


The domain of $x,y$ comes from the while statements, and that they increment by $1$ each time.
The claim it is within a circle comes from the if statement.
The choice of $f$ comes from how $s$ increments: $s \mapsto s + x^2$.


This would be an approximation to the integral
$$
\iint\limits_{x^2 + y^2 < 1000^2} x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y
$$
In polar form,
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{1000} r^2 \cos^2 \theta \, r \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\theta
$$
Per Wolfram this is about $8 \times 10^{11}$. So ultimately this seems to be the same conclusion, albeit via a different process.

I am still thinking about the integrand, being $x^2$, not $x^2+y^2$?
Secondly, how to evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{1000} r^2 \cos^2 \theta , r , \mathrm{d}r , \mathrm{d}\theta$ in a fast way, without a calculator, (or even estimate it)? BTW (+1).

The $x^2+y^2$ bit only appears in the "if" statement, in order to ensure we add up evaluations within $x^2+y^2<1000^2$. Notice that the running total "$s$" only gets $x^2$ added to it in those conditions, not $x^2+y^2$.
As for how to evaluate it, the only real point of difficulty would be the cosine term. We can have it be
$$
\left( \int_0^{1000} r^3 , \mathrm{d}r \right) \left( \int_0^{2\pi} \cos^2 \theta , \mathrm{d}\theta \right)
$$
and
$$
\cos^2 \theta = \frac{1+\cos 2 \theta}{2}
$$
making the $\theta$ integral trivial.

Got it. Thanks a lot!

The region of integration is $x^2 + y^2 < 10^{6}$
$\displaystyle \int_{-1000}^{1000}\int_{-\sqrt {10^6-x^2}}^{\sqrt{10^6 - x^2}} x^2\ dy\ dx$
Up to you if you want to convert to polar.
